# Unable to get intent from service with LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

so i have 2 activity and 1 service.

- Mainactivity (for activating the service)
- Service (for detecting shake gesture)
- Targetactivity (for displaying how many shake)

i did many tutorials and advice from simillar question but still cannot get an intent from targetactivity

this is my code looks like.
Service.java

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        ShakeListener shakeListener = new ShakeListener(this);
        mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(shakeListener);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

ShakeListener.java

```
@Override
public void onShake(int count) {
        sendCountBroadcast(count);
        if(count == threshold ){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,TargetActivity.class); //showing target activity when shake == threshold
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);


        }

    }

    private void sendCountBroadcast(int count) {
        if (count != 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(COUNTER_SHAKE);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNT, count);
            //ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

TargetActivity.java

```
TextView tvCounter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_target);
        tvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ShakeListener.COUNTER_SHAKE));


    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int count = intent.getIntExtra(ShakeListener.EXTRA_COUNT,0);
            tvCounter.setText(count);
        }
    };
```

Manifest for service:

```
<service android:process=":sensordetect"
         android:name=".Service"
         android:enabled="true"></service>
```

`sendCountBroadCast` is called but `OnReceive` method is not called

Anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` does not work across separate processes. Your `Service` is in a different process - `android:process=":sensordetect"`.

Comment: it still cannot work if i add/delete process @MikeM.

Comment: You've got the wrong action set on the `IntentFilter` in the `Activity` - `new IntentFilter(ShakeListener.EXTRA_COUNT)`. That should be `ShakeListener.COUNTER_SHAKE`.

Comment: omg i'm in rush haha, beginner's mistake and also i have deleted the process. and it's working. thank you, you saved my time.